# A problem with the definition of limit for functions of the form $f : \{ a \} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, first-order-logic

This is a technical concern of mine, so I will be using a lot of formal notation. I am using Tao's extended notation (from his Analysis I) to make the domain explicit and bound as a variable in the definition.

**Definition.** Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$. Then,

$$
\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in D}f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow \forall\varepsilon > 0.\exists\delta > 0.\forall x \in D.(0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon).
$$

Now consider a function with a singleton as a domain, i.e., $f : \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}$ and consider the limit $\lim_{x\to a;x \in \{a\}}f(x)$. Then, the premise of the defining implication is trivially true, since $|x - a| = 0$ for all $x \in \{ a \}$. This means that every $L \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit of this function at $a$. Thus, the limit is not unique. If we take the symbols

$$
\lim_{x\to x_0;x\in D}f(x) = L
$$

to mean a formula with the equality predicate, we have even derived a contradiction, as our above case implies that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}.(x = y)$. This is fixed by interpreting the above symbols as a relation $\mathrm{LIM}(f, D, x_0, L)$. The failure of uniqueness also implies that our $f$ both is and isn't continuous at $f$. This is a problem.

Have I made a mistake in my deduction, and if not, how can we fix this definition?

Comment: I think you mean "the premise of the defining implication is trivially false" since it is never the case that $x\in\{a\}$ satisfies $0 < |x-a|<\delta$. (The $0 < \dots$ part fails.)

Comment: Indeed, the way the definition is spelled out, there is no unique „the“ limit in case of isolated points. One way to avoid thus is by defining limits (of functions at points) only if every punctured neighbour is non-empty.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Sure, you can word it like that. But my wording is also correct, since I claim that the *implication* is trivially true, which happens by explosion when the premise is false.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the feedback. It's interesting to me that I have never seen this caveat explicitly mentioned. How would one proceed in the case of singleton domains? I guess you would just define the images to be limits, and then everything else works out, right?

Comment: Can't you just use $0\le$ instead of $0<$ or am I missing something? Then $x_0$ ensures uniqueness.

Comment: @Matija I think this implies that every function which has a limit at $a$ is continuous at $a$, which is undesirable, since it may not even be defined at $a$.

Comment: It's true that the implication holds trivially in this situation. This does have the consequence that any $L$ is the limit. It's not really a problem per se because the notion of a limit aims to capture the behavior of a function *near, but not at* a point: the fact that any $L$ is the limit in this situation means this definition, when applied to singletons, has no content. It suggests we only consider limits at non-isolated points.

Comment: @Matija I take that back, actually.

Comment: Okay, because we still have $x\in D$, right? Also, any function defined on a singelton is both continuous and sequentially continuous :-) I know that punctured neighborhoods are sometimes used in situations like these, but I never really understood why.

Comment: @Matija Or not... The problem is that this definition messes up our intuitive understanding of limits. Non-continuous functions, per your suggestion, don't have limits when approaching their discontinuous points, because the implication fails at $x = x_0$. Consider for example the function $f(x) = 0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise. By your definition, the limit of $f$ at $0$ is not $0$, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Matija It would take some work to show that under your definition, non-continuity (using the standard definition with limits) implies the non-existence of a limit, but now I'm progressively more convinced that this is right.
Indeed, let's say that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$. Then $f(x_0) \neq \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) \neq L$ by definition. Thus, if an appropriate $L$ exists, $|f(x_0) - L|$ is fixed and non-zero. Thus, we can choose the appropriately small $\varepsilon$ to falsify the definition. I believe this is QED.

Comment: Fair point, but then functions on discrete subspaces of the reals are not sequentially continuous, that's also wild, right? It kinda conflicts with the equivalence of the two continuity types for metric spaces and functions with discrete topology on the domain being continuous...

Comment: My last comment addressed your second to last comment :-)

Comment: I guess you're familiar with [this](https://planetmath.org/sequentiallycontinuous) definition of sequential continuity. For metric spaces, this coincides with the definition using unpunctured balls, since the trivial sequence is allowed. If you specifically want the two-sided limit, you could still use $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0;x\in D\setminus\{x_0\}}$. At least that's how I would define and use the notions, if I would teach calculus :-) When it comes to research, you'd use whatever definition is more convenient in the given context, because I don't think there exists a golden standard here.